# Mysql - get latest history record for each family

Tags: mysql

I need to get the latest history item (from a certain category - 1422) for every family in the DB.
I saw several examples around, and came to this query:

```
SELECT *, MAX(created_at) 
FROM family_histories
WHERE family_history_cat_id = 1422
GROUP BY family_id
```

Is it good?

Comment: Your going to need to provide a lot more information than that ! your schema for example, some sample data, expected output  ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN too get MAX id for each group

```
SELECT
  fh.*
FROM family_histories
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
        family_history_cat_id,
        MAX(created_at)
          FROM family_histories
          GROUP BY family_id) AS l
    ON l.family_history_cat_id = fh.family_history_cat_id
WHERE fh.family_history_cat_id = 1422
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM family_histories
WHERE family_history_cat_id = 1422
GROUP BY family_id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```